# Proving that $\frac{1}{(2k+1)^4} - 2 \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}\right)$ is non negative

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

Prove that the sequence

$$s_k = \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4} - 2 \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}\right)$$ is non-negative.

I would appreciate an *elementary proof*. I tried using series / integral comparison without success.

This question is a follow up of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833512/errors-are-decreasing-in-series-sum-n-1-infty-1n-n4). There is an answer to that question that uses the integral representation of [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), that I'd like to avoid... if possible!

Comment: Just at first glance, have you tried factoring the $2n$ from the denominator of the right-hand term and using derivatives of geometric series to obtain some bounds? I haven’t worked through it but would first attempt it this way. (I’m guessing you have tried it since you mention attempts involving series, but I don’t know what exactly you’ve tried so leaving a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = 1/x^4$ is strictly convex, so that
$$
 \frac{1}{(2n)^4} < \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} \right) 
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{(2n)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}  < \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} \right) 
$$
It follows that
$$
2 \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} \right)
< \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} \right) = \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4} \, .
$$

Comment: I think you made a typo - $\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$ should be $\frac{1}{(2n)^4}$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla: Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta_k=\frac{1}{(2k+1)^4} - 2 \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n)^4} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^4}=\frac{1}{96} \psi ^{(3)}(k+1)\qquad \qquad\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}=\frac{1}{96} \psi ^{(3)}\left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ Using asymptotics
$$\Delta_k=\frac 1 {16k^5} \left(1-\frac{5}{2 k}+\frac{25}{8 k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)$$